# Java Classes in Nashorn

Tags: java, nashorn

I need to compile many JavaScript files to run in Nashorn.  Do each of these files generate a Java class?  Do these Java classes have file handles in the operating system?

Comment: Take look at some of the examples [here](https://github.com/shivasaxena/java-nashorn-examples). You'll have .js and .java files. Javascript files are never compiled, just interpreted as they usually are in their "native" web environment.

Answer (score 2):

Compile JavaScript? Nashorn is just an engine that [interprets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/nashorn/introduction.htm) Javascript, that's all. That said, there are no classes generated for your Javascript files.